# Is disconnected workflows available with viewer V7 api

Tags: autodesk-forge

I try to use the workflows from " https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/disconnected-workflows " .
I use the .net core and sucess with viewer V6 , but when I try to use the V7 that console comes out of the error message  "
GET https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2/manifest/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dGVzdF8wMTA2L3JhY2Jhc2ljc2FtcGxlcHJvamVjdC5ydnQ?domain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3060 net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED "

This message occurred when I try to use service-worker offline the website and load the model I have cashed.
How can I fix it or other way to get the same result?
I am not sure that the problem is in the part I try to load the document or not.

I use this code

```
export function loadModel_cache(urn) {
  let viewerError = document.getElementById("viewer-error");
  if (viewerError) {
    viewerError.parentNode.removeChild(viewerError);
  }

  function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
    viewerError = document.createElement("div");
    viewerError.id = "viewer-error";
    viewerError.innerHTML =
      "<span>Could not load document. Are you offline?</span>";
    document.getElementById("preview").appendChild(viewerError);
    updateOverlay();
    console.error("Could not load document " + urn);
  }
  function onItemLoadSuccess(viewer) {}
  function onItemLoadFailure() {
    updateOverlay();
    console.error("Could not load model from document " + urn);
  }
  currentUrn = null;
  const status = document.querySelector(
    `#overlay > ul > li[data-urn="${urn}"] > .model-status`
  );
  status.style.setProperty("display", "inline");
  status.innerHTML = "(loading...)";
  Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
    "urn:" + urn,
    (doc) => {
      const viewables = doc.getRoot().search({ type: "geometry" });
      console.log(viewables);
      console.log(doc);
      currentApp.loadDocumentNode(doc, viewables[0]).then(() => {
        onItemLoadSuccess();
        currentUrn = urn;
        updateOverlay();
      }); // Assuming there's always at least one viewable
    },

    onDocumentLoadFailure
  );
```

replace this one that use in the source code

```
function loadModel(urn) {
  let viewerError = document.getElementById("viewer-error");
  if (viewerError) {
    viewerError.parentNode.removeChild(viewerError);
  }

  function onDocumentLoadSuccess() {
    const viewables = currentApp.bubble.search({ type: "geometry" });
    console.log(viewables);
    currentApp.selectItem(
      viewables[0].data,
      onItemLoadSuccess,
      onItemLoadFailure
    ); // Assuming there's always at least one viewable
  }
  function onDocumentLoadFailure() {
    viewerError = document.createElement("div");
    viewerError.id = "viewer-error";
    viewerError.innerHTML =
      "<span>Could not load document. Are you offline?</span>";
    document.getElementById("viewer").appendChild(viewerError);
    updateOverlay();
    console.error("Could not load document " + urn);
  }
  function onItemLoadSuccess(viewer) {
    viewer.addEventListener(
      Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT,
      function () {
        currentUrn = urn;
        updateOverlay();
      }
    );
  }
  function onItemLoadFailure() {
    updateOverlay();
    console.error("Could not load model from document " + urn);
  }
  currentUrn = null;
  const status = document.querySelector(
    `#overlay > ul > li[data-urn="${urn}"] > .model-status`
  );
  status.style.setProperty("display", "inline");
  status.innerHTML = "(loading...)";
  console.log(currentApp); //---------------------------------
  currentApp.loadDocument(
    "urn:" + urn,
    onDocumentLoadSuccess,
    onDocumentLoadFailure
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Newer versions of the viewer may be talking to different backend services so if you wanted to enable the "disconnected workflows" there, it should be possible, you would just need to update the types of URLs the service workers should cache.

Currently the service worker code [here](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-disconnected/blob/master/public/service-worker.js#L180) assumes that all the derivatives are coming from `https://developer.api.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2`, and as you found out already, newer versions of the viewer are actually pulling the data from `https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2`.

Also, be careful about the [SVF vs SVF2](https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/update-svf2-ga-new-streaming-web-format-forge-viewer-now-production-ready) format difference. You will only be able to cache SVF data, not SVF2.

Comment: Thank you very much . It works sucessfully with V7 viewer ! 

I have two questions about this work flow :
1. Can https://cdn.derivative.autodesk.com/derivativeservice/v2 this API can be changed with the modelderivative API? Because I think the output data contains the similar content that just with different format.
2.Does it have any possibility to cache SVF2 model ? I afraid that SVF format will be deprecated like other service be deprecated after Direct-S3 migration.

Comment: Re #1: I also think both APIs will serve the same content so it should be fine migrating to it.

Comment: Re #2: I'm not aware of any plans to deprecate SVF. The optimized SVF2 format is based on SVF anyway, and I think SVF will still be useful in certain scenarios such as this caching one.

Comment: I see . I will try the  modelderivative external API and readjust the output of it !